# Can the focus of a Microsoft LifeCam HD-5000 be fixed at infinity under linux?

Tags: ubuntu, video, camera, motion

I have two Microsoft LifeCam HD-5000 webcams which I am using as a home security system with the [Motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) package for linux. One problem I have is that because these webcams have auto-focus, sometimes they will try to automatically adjust the focus and will create false positive motion detection.

It seems like you can fix the focus at infinity under windows. Is there any way I could do that under linux, using `uvcvideo`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this works:

```
uvcdynctrl -s "Focus, Auto" 0
```

You can then adjust the focus with:

```
uvcdynctrl -s "Focus (absolute)" $amt
```

Where `$amt` is a number from 0 - 40

Comment: This looks very promising, however I don't have `uvcdynctrl` on my Ubuntu box. I will investigate further and post back. Thanks!

Comment: @user4646 On the off-chance you read this, can you tell more about the meaning of the range? Which is infinity? Also, where did you find this information, I've tried --help and info and neither give this range or information. Thanks!